# Memory efficient sorting C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector, selection-sort

I am looking for less memory consuming way of sorting vector. Atm I am using this solution:

```
void selectionSort(int arg[], int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < size+1; j++){
        if(arg[j]<arg[min]){
            min = j;
            }
        if(min != i){
            int temp1 = arg[min];
            int temp2 = arg[i];
            arg[min] = temp2;
            arg[i] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> file;

    ifstream in(argv[1]);

    if(in.good())
    {
    string line;
    while(getline(in, line)){
        stringstream lineStream(line);
        int value;
        while(lineStream >> value){
            file.push_back(value);
            }
        }

    int * tab;
    tab = new int [file.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++){
        tab[i] = file.at(i);
        cout << tab[i] << ",";
        }
    cout << endl;

    selectionSort(tab, file.size());

    for(int n = 0; n < file.size(); n++){
    cout << tab[n] << ",";
    }

    delete[] tab;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to use vector instead of dynamic array that I used like this?
I'm getting unchanged vector in my output.

```
void selectionSort(vector<int> arg){
    for(int i = 0; i < arg.size(); i++){
    int min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < arg.size()+1; j++){
        if(arg[j]<arg[min]){
            min = j;
            }
        if(min != i){
            int temp1 = arg[min];
            int temp2 = arg[i];
            arg[min] = temp2;
            arg[i] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is fragment of main func:

```
selectionSort((file));

for(int n = 0; n < file.size(); n++){
    cout << file.at(n) << ",";
    }

}

return 0;
```

Comment: Pass the vector by reference: `void selectionSort(vector<int>& arg){`. Also you can simply use `std::sort()`.

Comment: Thank you!, It works flawlessly now. I'm learning sorting methods atm, that's why I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

How to implement sorting algorithms from scratch:

In case you are further interested in learning about other comparison based sorting algorithms like: (1) merge sort, (2) insertion sort, and (3) quick sort. Please check the Stanford CS106B: Programming Abstractions. The youtube playlist is the following: 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFE6E58F856038C69

The specific lectures are 14, 15, 16. The professor implements all these algorithms from scratch, and comparatively explains these algorithms considering speed, memory efficiency.

Note: However, the professor assumes that the students have very basic knowledge of arrays, pointers and linked-list. If you do not have such basic please start from lecture 12.

All the best. Please ignore the typos.